# The application does not install a second time

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I sign the `APK`, I choose the type of `Debug`, I distribute it directly, I will not upload it to `Google Play`.

I install. But the problem is that I try install the same `APK` back, it does not install writes.

1) I tried to delete, delete for all users and again, all in vain. One version helps, I raise `version code` to 2, `version name` to 1.1, sign and roll back this data and sign again. Only then installed.

2) Disabled “Check security threats” on Google Play, and works fine

3) Even if you put it on `Google Play` in closed testing and from there download the `APK` and install, the problem disappears

Then again, install the same `APK` does not work.

Maybe someone came across this, tell me?

Comment: What command are you using to install?

Comment: I sign the APK and install it.

Comment: how do you install it?

Comment: I click on the `APK file` in the storage and the message "Install?" I click "YES" and the installation process continues

Comment: You need to bump the version code each time

Comment: Yes, I know, but because of this I completely uninstall the application and reinstall it. But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ADB, you need to use the `-r` flag,

here is the docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb

Here is the command:

`adb install -r path_to_apk`

[image]

---

When installing from a downloaded file the `versionCode` *always* needs to be higher than the one currently installed to allow for a new installation.

> versionCode — A positive integer used as an internal version number. This number is used only to determine whether one version is more recent than another, with higher numbers indicating more recent versions. This is not the version number shown to users; that number is set by the versionName setting, below. The **Android system uses the versionCode value to protect against downgrades by preventing users from installing an APK with a lower versionCode than the version currently installed on their device**.
>
> The value is a positive integer so that other apps can programmatically evaluate it, for example to check an upgrade or downgrade relationship. You can set the value to any positive integer you want, however you should make sure that each successive release of your app uses a greater value. You cannot upload an APK to the Play Store with a versionCode you have already used for a previous version.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning

Comment: Yes, I know, but because of this I completely uninstall the application and reinstall it. But it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

find the project in Your projects_folder for example

and go into your Project which is not install........

go into the **gradle**/.....and find the **apk** folder and delete it

1. *MyComputer/D/Newfolder/*.....
   2.go into the **gradle**/.....and find the **apk** folder and delete it
   3.After all run project again